# How to show/display/read/edit xlsx content in android activity using docx4j?

Tags: android, xlsx, docx4j

I am new to using `docx4j` library, I am trying to open the `xlsx` file using API's provided by docx4j. I am able to load the file by using `SpreadsheetMLPackage`

```
xlsMLPackage = (SpreadsheetMLPackage)loader.get(is1);
```

I don't know how to show the file content in activity in android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own code to provide a user interface.

Comment: i understand that, but i didnot get what are the API's available to fetch the file contents? is there any API guide which will help me to go through available API's.

Comment: There is http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2013/05/docx4j-in-a-single-page/ and a Getting Started document, linked from http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j